# I want to make my php know if there is a number in the password

Tags: javascript, php

I want to know if there is a number in one string (PHP CODE)
This is what i have:

```
if (!preg_match('/0/',$p) || !preg_match('/1/',$p) || !preg_match('/2/',$p) || !preg_match('/3/',$p) || !preg_match('/4/',$p) || !preg_match('/5/',$p) || !preg_match('/6/',$p) || !preg_match('/7/',$p) || !preg_match('/8/',$p) || !preg_match('/9/',$p)){
    echo "<p>The password need to contain atleast one number</p>";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Might I suggest using `if(!preg_match('\d+', $p))`? That will match on having at least one number in the string.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Good point on the shorthand class `\d`, but you should probably suggest delimiters too. Also, testing whether _a_ `\d` exists, `+` is unnecessary.

Comment: That's a valid pint, @Wiseguy. I'm just in the habit of using `+` (to make the intent clear) (well, as much as regex can be clear)

Answer (score 3):

I think this one is better:

```
if(!preg_match('#[0-9]#', $p))
```

So that way you can avoid that unnecessary `if` jungle.

Test it [here](http://ideone.com/dknGZM).

Answer (score 3):

This should be what you're looking for.

```
if (!preg_match('/[0-9]/',$p)) {
    echo "<p>The password need to contain at least one number</p>";
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using this:

```
  if (!preg_match('/\d/',$p)) {
    echo "<p>The password need to contain at least one number</p>";
    exit();
}
```